# struggling to understand some cookie/database shopping cart concepts

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am trying to get my head around how to correctly implement a shopping cart based on saving a cookie with a unique identifier to identify a users shopping cart in the database whether the user is logged in or as shopping a guest. I've tried to look at as many examples as i can, but i am not understanding it clearly enough.

Here's how i have it so far:

[Guest user]

1. Create cookie with unique id when user adds item to cart
2. Check for existing cart associated with cookie ID in database
3. If cart does not exist, create entry in DB table 'cart_id' with the cookie ID as session identifier
4. create entry in DB table 'cart_items' with the cookie ID as an identifier

[Logged in user]

1. Check for existing cart in DB table 'cart_id' associated with username and cookie ID
2. If cart exists, rewrite new cookie ID with cookie ID from database
3. If cart does not exist, assign username ID to table 'cart_id' with users unique cookie ID

**Here is where i am having troubles:**, all the previous is well and good,  assuming the user hadn't only decided to login after filling their cart which is where i am going wrong. Here's what i have:

1. Check for existing cart in DB table 'cart_id' associated with username and cookie ID
2. If cart does not exist, assign username to 'cart_id' table
3. If cart already exists, rewrite new cookie ID with existing cookie ID stored in database
4. rewrite 'new' cart items(items chosen while not logged in) with the users stored cookie ID
5. Check for duplicate cart items from existing cart and new cart items
6. If duplicate items are found, delete old items and replace with new item quantities

etc etc So basically i dont think it's going too well, though i currently works okay, it seems i am going a really crappy way about it.

How can i better handle a registered users shopping cart if they choose to log in after they have filled their shopping cart? Will i need to have a separate table for guest users and registered users, how can i transfer a guest shopping cart list to the registered users shopping cart if they log in after they pick their cart?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off at storing every ordered item (or the whole shopping cart content) locally, either through localStorage or cookie.

The way you do it, you're doing too much request on your DB. Why? Because you're assuming a cookie is something reliable, and in fact, it is not. So all of your operations using "cookie ID" are for nothing if the user chooses to reset his browser / delete his cookies.

There are many ways a cookie can be destroyed, at least it's harder with localStorage.

I would say : store it locally, and if logged, sync what has been saved locally with what is on the DB. But don't store unlogged users shopping carts on the DB : eventually you'll end up with orphans (no more cookie present for some reason), and you won't be able to understand why.

Comment: I will do some research into local storage. Though to be fair if the cookie is destroyed only a guest user would be affected in this scenario and when a registered user logs in a new cookie is either overwritten or generated based on stored unique cookie id associated with their username in the DB.